# Uncaught TypeError: Object Indtast CPR-nummeret, der skal valideres. has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm currently developing a new website and I'm testing the features right now. Alle my code works, but returns an error, that I don't understand nor know how to solve.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var eval = "Indtast CPR-nummeret, der skal valideres.";
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#showads").html($("#ads").html());
});
function cprToBool(cpr){
    $.get('ajax.php',{ content: cpr }, function(data) {
        eval = data;
        $("#cprinput").val(eval);
        $("#cprinput").blur();
        });
             $("#showads").html($("#ads").html());   
}
function checkSubmit(e)
{
  if(e && e.keyCode == 13)
   {
    cprToBool($("#cprinput").val());
   }
}
</script>
```

After debugging, I'm pretty sure it's

```
$("#showads").html($("#ads").html());
```

that is causing these errors. It returns

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object Indtast CPR-nummeret, der skal valideres. has no method 'call'
```

which is the name of the `eval` variable.
Anyone get why it's doing this?

PS. I've included jQuery correctly.

Comment: Why are you overriding the built-in `eval` method?

Comment: Oops. That explains a lot.

Comment: What browser (version) are you using, and what data format does your ajax call return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the variable from `eval` to something else...`eval2` would be fine.

Something in the jQuery library is attempting to use the built-in `eval` method and can't be done because you've overwritten it with a string...which is not callable.

jQuery uses this code several times:

```
window[ "eval" ].call
```

And since you declared your `eval` variable in the global scope, `window[ "eval" ]` is being overwritten. If you declared it in a different scope (somehow), it wouldn't conflict with jQuery code, but you wouldn't be able to use the built-in `eval` method in that scope anymore.

Comment: Dumb me. I won't do that twice :-)

Comment: @RoboForm Haha no problem. Are you only using the `eval` variable inside of the `$.get`? It seems that you're setting it, then immediately getting it, and never using it again in the rest of your code. That may be because you didn't post your whole code, but if that's all your code, there's no reason to use a global variable anyways

Comment: A textbox uses it somewhere, which is the reason why it's global :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers/comments here are correct, your overwriting `eval` has caused other pieces of code to trip up. You can change the variable name, as suggested, although better advice IMO would actually be to have localised variables; as long as you're not planning on using `eval` in the scope of your own code, overwriting it is **much** less of a no-no and not a problem at all, as long as your variables are only visible to your code.